# Prove that if $A = B$ then $A \backslash B = B \backslash A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove that if $A = B$ then $A \backslash B = B \backslash A$

I tried to use the Axiom of Extentionality: $$A = B \iff x\in A \leftrightarrow x\in B$$ 
And so now I get two implications: $$x \in A \rightarrow x \in B$$
and $$x\in B \rightarrow x\in A$$
Now, I tried to apply Modus Tollens; 
$$\neg (x\in B) \rightarrow \neg(x\in A)
$$
and $$\neg(x \in A) \rightarrow \neg(x \in B)$$
And so we have (1): $$x \notin A \iff x\notin B$$
We have $x \in A \backslash B \iff x \in A \land x\notin B$
 and $x\in B\backslash A \iff x\in B \land x\notin A$ 
Which, in light of (1), is an empty set. 
Have I proved it correctly?

Comment: Are you working in a logic system where equality is not primitive? In most settings it would be easier to know in general that $t_1=t_2 \Rightarrow (\varphi(t_1)\Rightarrow \varphi(t_2))$ and in particular $$A=B \Rightarrow (A\setminus A = A\setminus A \Rightarrow A\setminus B = B\setminus A)$$ where $t_1\equiv A$, $t_2\equiv B$, $\varphi(x)\equiv  A\setminus x = x\setminus A$.

Comment: @Mauro: (1) is the last displayed formula (labeled in the line above it).

Comment: From the fact that6 $A=B$ and the def of $x \in A \setminus B$ as $x \in A \land x \notin B$ we can imemdiately get: $x \in A \setminus B \Leftrightarrow x \in A \land x \notin A$.

Comment: If $A=B$ then $A\setminus B=\color{red}{\emptyset}=B\setminus A$

Comment: Should say that since $x \notin A$ and $x \notin B$ are logically equivalent, we can replace either by the other in any statement.

Answer (score 1):

Show that if A = B, then A - B = empty set and B - A = empty set.